# showing mnist digits using python, numpy and matplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mnist

Let assume that I have MNIST digits in variable L.

`L[0].reshape(28,28)` will give me opportunity to plot this with matplot:
`plt.matshow(L[0].reshape(28,28))`.

But what if I want to plot 25 digits in 5x5 grid I cannot figure out how to shuffle L[0:24] to draw it properly with matplot.

maybe anyone will have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be something like that:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,5)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()):
    ax.imshow(L[i].reshape(28,28))
```

That way you can loop over your subplots.
If you like to shuffle the order of your plots you can use `np.random.permutation(25)` this will permute your indices:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,5)
for i, ax in zip(np.random.permutation(25), axes.ravel()):
    ax.imshow(L[i].reshape(28,28))
```

Comment: BTW - is there any possibility to put many letters on the ONE subplot insted of many separate subplots?

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: You mean like a suplot of subplots? Can you maybe just create more subplots? Would that help? What exactly do you like to display?